# Extract specific words from String in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I want to extract all the words that are before "indices" (i.e ForeverTrophyless, NoPainNoGame, Prize) and put em all inside a list. How Can I do that?

```
foo = '[{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[0,18]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[19,37]},{"text":"Prize","indices":[38,56]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[57,75]},{"text":"NoPainNoGame","indices":[76,94]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[95,113]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[114,132]}]'
```

### Python2.7

Pycharm
Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `[x['text'] for x in foo]`. Also, there's no such thing like "before" in dictionaries, because they're unordered.

Comment: @vaultah Sorry friend I forgot  the ' ' in my question, foo is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn that string into a list of dictionaries.

```
foo = '[{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[0,18]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[19,37]},{"text":"Prize","indices":[38,56]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[57,75]},{"text":"NoPainNoGame","indices":[76,94]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[95,113]},{"text":"ForeverTrophyless","indices":[114,132]}]'

import ast
l = ast.literal_eval(foo)
```

`l` is now:

```
[{'indices': [0, 18], 'text': 'ForeverTrophyless'},
 {'indices': [19, 37], 'text': 'ForeverTrophyless'},
 {'indices': [38, 56], 'text': 'Prize'},
 {'indices': [57, 75], 'text': 'ForeverTrophyless'},
 {'indices': [76, 94], 'text': 'NoPainNoGame'},
 {'indices': [95, 113], 'text': 'ForeverTrophyless'},
 {'indices': [114, 132], 'text': 'ForeverTrophyless'}]
```

Then use a list comprehension

```
[i['text'] for i in l]
```

Result

```
['ForeverTrophyless', 'ForeverTrophyless', 'Prize', 'ForeverTrophyless', 'NoPainNoGame', 'ForeverTrophyless', 'ForeverTrophyless']
```

Answer (score 2):

`foo` appears to be a valid serialized JSON object. You can parse it with [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#json.loads) and then retrieve all `text` fields inside a list comprehension:

```
In [8]: from json import loads

In [9]: [x['text'] for x in loads(foo)]
Out[9]: 
['ForeverTrophyless',
 'ForeverTrophyless',
 'Prize',
 'ForeverTrophyless',
 'NoPainNoGame',
 'ForeverTrophyless',
 'ForeverTrophyless']
```

Comment: Yes, is part of a JSON object. Thanks for your help, You're right!